# Qual é a vantagem de frameworks front-end como react?

Tags: front-end, react

Estava conversando com alguns amigos e na conversa me disseram que frameworks como react seriam obrigatórias para a programação front end hoje em dia.

Queria saber a opinião de vocês sobre isto, sobre por que usar uma linguagem front end e se não utilizar você será excluído do mercado.

Além disto quais são as vantagens de se usar um "framework" front end e por que devemos utilizar.

Comment: Antes que comecem a chover comentários de que a questão é muito subjetiva: a pergunta é interessante, porém tem coisas que não dá pra dizer – como prever o que vai acontecer no "mercado" no futuro. A última frase, porém, acho totalmente respondível.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um framework front end agrupa varias funcionalidades e facilita boa parte do seu trabalho. Utilizando um framework você encontrará muitas facilidades como:

- Reutilização de codigo
- Mais Velocidade no desenvolvimento
- Maior facilidade de encontrar soluções
- Funções mais otimizadas (Os frameworks possuem time de especilista trabalhando na melhora frequente dos metodos)
- Redução de erros (Pois as funções ja foram testadas por varias outros devs)
- Abstração da solução, você vai se preocupar mais com o por quê, do que com o como fazer.

Acredito que estas vantagens ja são um otimos motivo para usar frameworks. Como profissional acredito que o domínio de um framework gera destaque no mercado. Seus amigos estão certo, não existem hoje sistemas feitos sem o auxilio de algum framework.

Comment: Então a tendência do mercado é toda aplicação usar React, Vue ou Angular e outros frameworks front que estão surgindo no momento?

Além do mais o Wordpress, OpenCart, Grav possuem pouquissimos templates bons utilizando frameworks como React ou linguagens front end.

Você não acha que ainda é muito cedo para utiliza-lo em toda aplicação? Por exemplo se eu faço um blog em Wordpress, por que eu deveria utilizar React? 

Acha mesmo que deve ser aplicado em todo sistema?

Comment: Não acho que seja cedo, o framework so vai se establizar se usado, se ficarmos esperando demais para usa-lo ele simplesmente perderá o sentido. Os templetes demoram a se adaptar a tecnologias, pois existe a curva de aprendizado de quem os desenvolve. A escolhe de qual framework é muito sensivel, você pode se basear em N fatores, mas acaba sendo um pouco de intuição de mercado. Você deveria usar react pois desenvolverá mais rapido, com mais segurança e qualidade, alcançando um melhor resultado, apenas isso deve bastar para que você escolha algum dos varios fraework.